# How to get tasks that match logged in user id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

In Controller:

```
$user = user()->id;
$tasks = task::with('user')->where('tasks.user_id', '=', '$user')->get();
```

Task Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function Tasks()
{
    /**
     * The relationship to the user's tasks.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Here is the error: Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = auth()->user()->id; //This line of code will give Authenticated user id.
$tasks = task::with('user')->where('tasks.user_id', '=', $user)->get(); //Remove single quate from $user variable
```

**Or**

```
$user = \Auth::user()->id; 
$tasks = task::with('user')->where('tasks.user_id', '=', $user)->get();
```

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()->id;` or `Auth::id();` to get the identity of the logged in user; you can use. For detailed information, you can check here: *https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```php
$tasks = Auth::user()->tasks;
```

and $tasks contains tasks that belongs to the current user

Comment: Mohammad Akbari, that works perfectly but how does Laravel know to go into the User's model and grab the tasks method?

Comment: Great question.
Excellent.

Before answer your question, you must know the laravel request lifecycle.

It is truly simple, but I can not explain it to you in comment section.

But for clarification, Auth object resolve the authenticated user, then on that object your code call the tasks method which leads to return a relation object that fetch data from database.